# need a form input into textbox with jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I want create a form same picture below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezVmO.jpg

or anythings same it.
and post.php can excute it as:

```
array[0] => 'User1'
....
array[9] => 'User9'
```

anyone can help me? sorry about my English.

Comment: Show us what until you have tried?

Comment: I still haven't code :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you please check this [jTags demo](http://www.benoitvidis.com/files/code/jtags/jtags.demo.htm) AND [tagging](http://remysharp.com/wp-content/uploads/2007/12/tagging.php)

Comment: Or [Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/)

Comment: thanks, jtags demo helped me./

Answer (score 0):

You should try this, http://xoxco.com/projects/code/tagsinput/ 
There are lot of other "Tagging" jquery plugins available.